# Validating JSON data

Tags: django, json, validation

I am using json in some AJAX request and am currently manually validating each entry using (if "key" in json.some_location.keys()) over and over again.

Is there a simpler way to do this (like XML validation)?

Note: I am open to validation libraries, but would like something I can drop into django itself (not python eggs).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JSON schema validators: http://barelyenough.org/blog/2007/07/json-schema-definition-languages/

Answer (score 0):

itemscript.org has a json schema and validator.